# How to handle classes that are not copyable?

Tags: c++

An example:

```
class File {
public:
    File(const char* path);
    File(File& other) = delete;
    File& operator=(File& rhs) = delete;
    ~File();

private:
    char* path;
    FILE* cfile;
};


class Filesystem {
public:
    Filesystem();
    Filesystem(Filesystem& other);
    ~Filesystem();

    File Search(const char* filepath) {
        File file(filepath);
        return file;
    }
private:
};
```

With the copy constructor and assignment operator deleted from the File class (because it shouldn't be copied), is there any way you can return it from the Search function of the filesystem or other ways to handle it?

Comment: Remove `File file(filepath);` change `return file;` to `return { filepath } ;` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/6TnEsoPTv

Comment: `because it shouldn't be copied` why shouldn't it be copied? `is there any way you can return it from the Search function` so if it should not be copied it should only be transferred? If so you probably looking for making it movable.

Comment: Problem is not in `File` but in code which uses it. You didn't show that code so how we can provide a good solution? (Pointer solution for me is stupid workaround when you do want to change problematic code).

Comment: @MarekR The code is in the Search() method of the Filesystem object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Moveable types

You can make the class [moveable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) by adding the move constructor and move assignment operator. ([Some possibly useful overview of that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/move-constructors-and-move-assignment-operators-cpp?view=msvc-170).)

```
...
// rough sketch
// Having the path as `char*` seems
//  bad (use std::string instead), 
//  but let's stick with the example as posted)
File(File&& other) 
: path(nullptr)
, cfile(nullptr)
{
  using std::swap;
  // steal the guts of the moved-from object
  swap(path, other.path);
  swap(cfile, other.cfile);
}
```

The move assignment operator can be a little bit [more tricky](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c65-make-move-assignment-safe-for-self-assignment), what with self-assigment checks.

/or/

### Smart pointers

You can wrap instances of these classes in a smart pointer and work with those:

- `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` etc.

```
    std::unique_ptr<File> Search(const char* filepath) {
        auto pfile = std::make_unique<File>(filepath);
        ...
        return pfile;
    }
```

This is especially helpful when you work with 3rd party classes (possibly legacy) that don't support move operations.

Yes, these have heap allocation overhead, but given the overhead of opening e.g. a file or acquiring another expensive resource that prevents copying, the heap allocation overhead might well be negligible.

Comment: I would suggest making it moveable first, and then fall back to pointer semantics if moveable doesn't fit, but otherwise solid suggestion